# the value in [] for insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: [] always/usually empty?

Tags: salesforce, sharing, error-messaging

What I'm more after is why the ID value in `[]` is typically null for this error when you know that the cross-reference ID has a value and if the error message just emitted the ID, you would know what SObject was the root cause, gaining valuable minutes/hours for your life.

Here's an example:

- OWD private on `Account`
- `Order` is controlled by parent
- running user profile has Modify All, View All on `Account` and View All on `Order`. Running user can view the Order via the UI. `Modify All` does not cascade down to Order even with `Controlled by parent`.
- Apex code attempts to insert a custom object `Order_Detail__c` underneath (not Master-detail) `Order`, providing a value for lookup field `Order_Detail__c.Order__c`

Now because there's no sharing rule extending r/w to the Order's Account in question, there's no r/w access to the Order and hence the `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY`, `insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []` error occurs when attempting to assign the child record to the parent Order.

What I don't understand is why the ID value of the field `Order_Detail__c.Order__c` lookup field is not emitted in the error message within the `[]`. Why are the brackets even there?

I suppose this is a security item and not exposing the ID value avoids telling the malefactor even what SObject can't be accessed. I'd be happy if the error message just displayed the first three chars - or converted to an sobjectType. The implication of `[]` is an empty array . but that is not what is going on in your code.

Is this hypothesis correct?

It sure makes life hard for the sysad who captures a debug log for the running user and then has to go through feats of deductive logic to figure out which related sobject (there could be several lookup fields on the object in question) is the problem one, let alone why.